# Notepad++ localization keeps reverting after closing

Tags: notepad++, localization

So, everytime I open Notepad++ it's in PTbr, for some unknown reason since I "installed" (on PortableApps.com platform) using ENus. And it doesn't matter if I change it inside the program's settings, everytime I close and re-open it, it reverts to PTbr. Already tried google, but no success. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on `config.xml`?

Comment: Yes, it's not set to read-only and I have writing access.

Comment: Strange. It works fine here. I'm using the LiberKey portable version of NPP. I can't imagine that's a lot different to the PortableApps version.